# Is it possible to speed up xarray-based code with numba?

Tags: numpy, numba, python-xarray

I have a codebase that makes heavy use of the *xarray* package. The computations (pointwise arithmetic, dot products, and built-in *numpy* ufuncs mostly) are already heavily vectorized. I was looking into *numba* for further speeding up this code. One reason is that the code is clearly not running parallelized (only one core used), so I thought that numba's `@jit(parallel=True)` decorator could help. (As far as I have tried, it doesn't.) Whenever I try to use `@jit(nopython=True)`, exceptions are raised, so I guess this means numba cannot handle the underlying xarray functions.

So:

- Has anyone successfully sped up xarray-based code using numba?
- If yes: How?
- If not: Are there reasons to try further or to abandon this attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the critical parts of the code you want to speed up can be cast as (generalized) ufuncs and optimized using [`numba.vectorize` or `numba.guvectorize`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/vectorize.html), you could then use [`xarray.apply_ufunc`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.apply_ufunc.html) to apply them to your xarray data with dimensions and broadcasting being automatically taken care of.

Depending on your code, it might also help or even be easier and/or be more useful to parallelize and optimize the computations using [the xarray Dask interface](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html). In many cases it can be as simple as calling the `.chunk()` method, performing the necessary operations and finally calling the `.compute()` method at the end.

To answer the first part of the question, yes, I use a combination of these approaches in my projects, [see here for a real-world example](https://github.com/smartass101/xrbispectral).

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party here, but https://github.com/numbagg/numbagg has a set of example functions and some helpful utilities for integrating numba & xarray.

xarray uses this library directly, for example this is how it implements exponential moving averages over n dimensions: https://github.com/numbagg/numbagg/blob/v0.2.1/numbagg/moving.py#L8

(disclosure — core dev of numbagg + xarray)

Answer (score 0):

I think numba with nopython=True should only be run with functions that use pure python or numpy code, no custom python objects like xarray.DataArrays. See "will Numba work for my code?", where it is specified that it will not work so well for optimizing operations that use pandas Dataframes.

"Note that Pandas is not understood by Numba and as a result Numba would simply run this code via the interpreter but with the added cost of the Numba internal overheads!" -

https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html

The same would be true of xarray I think.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your os is windows 10 or 11
Assuming you're doing this in a local environment

write your function in a separate .py file compile it
and then import it. this will allow you to use as many cores as you like.

don't define it in the same notebook or main.
This technique steps around "GIL" in windows python